# Get the NSMutableArray where an object is placed

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a NSMutableArray with objects of a custom subclass of CCNode. It looks like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
{
    CustomClass *cc = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
    [array addObject:cc];
}
```

From a function of CustomClass I want to get the NSMutableArray and the layer (Cocos2d) where the NSMutableArray is placed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a property to your class that owns array, and don't forget to synthesize it.
2. When you add things to your array like that, you'll want to release them after you add them, because adding them retains them.
3. Get the layer? Not enough information.